# Object.create from an object

Tags: javascript

All, If I pass an object into the `Object.create` , that means creating a new object inherit from  it. the code below proves it.

```
        function Shape() {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
        }

        Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;
            console.info("Shape moved.");
        };

        Rectangle = Object.create(Shape);
        Rectangle.__proto__==Shape;//it is true.yes, I can understand
        Rectangle//It is Function {} I can not understand it.
        Rectangle.constructor==Function//it is true.I can not understand it.
```

The diagram represent the relationship is below. But What I can not understand is the highlight part of it .What exactly is the `Rectangle`? I mean what is the `Function{}`, Where it come from? and also the `Rectangle.constructor` property, I don't know if all the object have the `constructor` property, and what does the `constructor` property use for? thanks.

PS: All the value above is caculated and watched in the FireBug.

[image]

**Correct the diagram by the minitech's comments**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's now how inheritance using `Object.create` works. It should look something like this:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype); // Leaving out the constructor business for simplicity
```

What you're doing there is duplicating the actual `Shape` function, so of course (being a function) its constructor is `Function`.

P.S. `Rectangle.__proto__ = Shape` isn't a comparison.

Comment: +1 - +2 more when you add some information about the constructor and what it does ;-)

Comment: @SeanVieira: Which constructor? `Function` or `Rectangle` or "sort-of `Rectangle`"? :D

Comment: Hi, all , Sorry for miss another more `=`, It should be '==', please review it again. thanks.

Comment: It should be the `Rectangle.__proto__ == Shape`

Comment: Hi, All , In my test code, I just want to create object inherit from `Shape` instead `Shape.prototype` , and try to figure it out what happen if did so. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: Nothing meaningful, really. `Rectangle.__proto__ === Shape` because that is its prototype now.

Comment: @minitech `===` or '==' ? seems there is a typo in your last comment? thanks.

Comment: @minitech In my question, I said I can understand the `Rectangle.__proto__ == Shape` because that is the way of `Object.create(Shape)` works, Please help to review the part of what I can't understand. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: Why it's a function is your entire question, right? Look at the second-to-last sentence...

Comment: @minitech this `constructor` property belong to the `Rectangle` or it's proto? thanks.

Comment: @minitech I doubted it come from `Function.prototype.constructor`, which is found by the prototype chains.

Comment: @Joe.wang: It comes from `Rectangle`. (Note that `typeof Rectangle === "object"` - it isn't a real function and can't be called, so it doesn't have its own `constructor`.)

Comment: @Joe.wang: So if you create `Rectangle` as `var Rectangle = Object.create(Shape);`, it has a `constructor` of `Function` because its prototype is `Shape` and `Shape.constructor` is `Function`. But it's not a *real* function; `new Rectangle()` throws a `TypeError` and `typeof Rectangle` is `'object'`.

Comment: @minitech I think `Shape.constructor` is coming from `Function.prototype`, so, the `constructor` actually from `Function.prototype`. I hope I am right . thanks.